# Issue introducing edgeDB to a current Sveltekit project

Tags: sveltekit, edgedb

I am trying to introduce edgeDB into a current sveltekit project.  No matter what configuration I try, I get the error below.  I have run "edgdb project init" and I have a dbschema directory already. I am missing something.  I haven't fully groked the whole edgeDB paradigm yet, but just experimenting to get off the runway.

```
ClientConnectionError: Found 'edgedb.toml' but the project is not initialized. Run `edgedb project init`.
```

edgedb.toml and dbschema are in the root directory with svelte.config.js and so forth.

svelte.config.ts

```
...
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        alias: {
            $dbschema: './dbschema',
            $db: 'dbschema/edgeql-js'
        }
    }
...
```

I have route/test/+page.server.ts:

```
import e from '$dbschema/edgeql-js';
import { client } from '$lib/db/edgedb';

import { selectPosts } from './queries';


export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({locals}) => {
    // const query = e.select(e.datetime_current());
    // const result = await query.run(client);
    // locals.datetime = result;

    //let posts = await selectPosts().run(client)
    selectPosts.run(client)

    return {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: {
            // datetime: result
            datetime: 'test'
        }
    };
}
```

route/test/+page.svelte

```
<script>
export let data;

</script>

{data.body.datetime}
```

routes/test/queries.ts

```
import e from '$dbschema/edgeql-js';

export const selectPosts = e.select(e.Post, () => {
    return {
        id: true,
        title: true
    };
});
```

lib/db/edgedb.ts

```
import { createClient } from 'edgedb'

export const client = createClient()
```

Comment: Have you run `edgedb project init` in your terminal?

Comment: Yes.  That was one of the first commands I ran.  I have a bunch of instances (e.g., edgedb instance list), so I believe I just have things quite munged up.